# Highcharts display value of the average with addPlotLine

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Looking at http://jsfiddle.net/0tfkfh2v/16/ which does what I want but it doesn't display the average amount - how would I get around this?

```
yAxis.addPlotLine({
    value: (sum/count),
    color: 'red',
    width: 2,
    id: 'avgLine'
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `label` inside `yAxis.addPlotLine({...})`

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/gufrxbnq/)

```
 yAxis.addPlotLine({
    value: (sum / count),
    label: {
      text: (sum / count).toFixed(2),
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      align: 'right',
      rotation: 0,
    },
    color: 'red',
    width: 2,
    id: 'avgLine'
  });
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you! If I have two lines, how do I get the average/plotline to focus on one in particular and dismiss the other?

Comment: can you create that example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44366741/highcharts-addplotline-for-one-set-of-values